# TwigSwiftMailer does not send e-mails

Tags: fosuserbundle, swiftmailer, symfony-2.3

I am developing a Symfony 2 site. that site sends e-mails to users using SwiftMailer.

The site uses FOSUserBundle to manage users access and it worked sending e-mails when I, for example request password reset. However, I need to add HTML capability to e-mails, so that I have configured FOSUserBundle to use TwigSwiftmailer instead, so, I changed the config file to the following:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb'
    from_email:
        address: info@ivexsolutions.com    
        sender_name: iVex Solutions
    firewall_name: main
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift    
    resetting:
        token_ttl: 43200    # 12 horas
        email:
            template:   DesytecGestionBundle:Resetting:email.txt.twig
    user_class: Desytec\GestionBundle\Entity\Usuario
```

After I changed that, mails are not being received by recipients. The most frustrating thing, is that the Send method call returns that it has correctly sent the email. Nothing is stored in log... I get no clue about what is happening here.

Can you advice me what to do to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance
Jaime

Comment: a strange thing is that I have configured mail sppol to be file... the message is created, however, when I use  swiftmailer:spool:send    commnd, the message disappears from the spool directory. but the command returns "Processing default mailer... 0 emails sent"

Answer (score 2):

Never mind... the problem was actually the from e-mail address. It was a forwarding address. I have created a real mailbox to it, and the e-mails were correctly sent.

Regards,
Jaime